# records not inserted in table of sqlite in ios using objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

Places table are created in gps_data.sqlite but places details not inserted.

```
sqlite3 *database;

@try
  {

NSString *query = nil;


    query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO Places( TRIPNAME ,STARTPLACE ,ENDPLACE ,DATE,TIME,MAXSPEED ,AVGSPEED ,TOTALTIME ,TOTALDISTANCE ,TRAVELMODE) VALUES ('%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@')",@"divya",@"home",@"office",@"date",@"time",@" MAXSPEED",@"AVGSPEED",@"totaltime",@"totaldistance",@"Walk"];


    //NSLog(@"queryyyyy//..%@",query);

    NSString *databasePath;
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Gps_data.sqlite"];


    ///NSLog(@"Update query = %@,  %@", query,databasePath );

    if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {

        int num = sqlite3_exec(database, [query UTF8String], NULL, NULL, NULL);
          NSLog(@"DB opened...%d", num);

    }
}

@catch (NSException * e) {

}

@finally {

    sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

Comment: what the error u faced, the **if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String]**, the function is executed or not

Comment: @ Anbu.Karthik records not inserted

Comment: my question is simple , the  if (sqlite3_open condition is caled or not

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik its called NSLog also printed

Comment: then open your sqlite and check , the data is inserted

Comment: your coding is correct , dont feel open your data base and check  once

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
sqlite3 *contactDB;
sqlite3_stmt    *statement;

const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
      {

       NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO CONTACTS (EMPID, DEPT, RATING,SUGGESTION) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%d\", \"%@\")", empIDtextField.text, strSegVal, ratingVal,[suggestnametextField.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

      const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];

      sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
      if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
           {
             //Success...
            }
      }
```

Comment: sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL);
            
            NSLog(@"DB opened...%d", num);
            
            if(sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_DONE)
            {
                NSLog(@"places details added to the database");
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"failed to add places details");
            }
its printing failed to add places details

Comment: @divyaswaminathan so its not inserting. debug line by line. first check wether database is created or not. also check wether you created table with proper field names.

Comment: Places table is created problem in insert records